# SQL random sampling into equal groups

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to randomly sample users in a table into 4 equal groups using SQL from a table. For that I did the below:

- First, randomize all users in the table using RANDOM() function, then use the result of it with  NTILE() function to divide them into 4 equal halves, like below:

```
WITH randomised_users AS (
       SELECT * 
         FROM users_table
      ORDER BY RANDOM()
) SELECT *, 
         ntile(4) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS tile_nr
    FROM randomised_users
```

Is this approach of sampling correct or is there a chance for bias in the 4 groups created from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks fine to me. You don't need a subquery BTW. This will do just fine

```
select *, ntile(4) over (order by random())
```

Snowflake doesn't guarantee the query will reproduce the same result set even if you provide a random seed so make sure to dump any intermediate result set into a temp table if you plan on re-using it.